# Two classes in one div, best approach - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm still new to styling with CSS. Here is my situation, I have three elements I want to one style. But each one needs small adjustments. So I gave each element the class of `plan-price` and then I gave them each a unique second class. Then I'm trying to nest the second class within the first. But that approach is not working. I'll show my code for clarity.

### HTML

```
    <div class="price-plans private-eye">
        <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="price-plans little-birdy">
        <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a></p>
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
 .plan-price {
    float: right;
    margin: 83px 20px 20px;

    .private-eye {
      margin: 40px;
    }

    .little-birdy {
      margin: 50px;
    }

  }
```

As you can see my attempt is to nest the second class within the first. I realize now that this does not work. What is another way I can do this?

Comment: Just as a tip, be careful nesting when you start using SCSS or whatever pre-processor. Your styles can get overly specific and then you'll be in a world of hurt. There is no need to nest these styles.

Comment: Okay, I hear ya. Thanks. Any advice on where my head should be when I run into a problem like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS by itself does not support nesting styles like this. You could just have the override styles after the "default" style and rely on the cascading nature of CSS to overwrite the margins.

```css
.plan-price {
  float: right;
  margin: 83px 20px 20px;
}
.plan-price.private-eye {
  margin: 40px;
}
.plan-price.little-birdy {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-plans private-eye">
  <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="price-plans little-birdy">
  <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

To do nesting styles, take a look at a CSS pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which lets you do exactly what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate the divs, give them id's. id = "whatever". Classes are used to make the divs have the same css styles when they are named the same class, but id's are used to style it individually. In your css file do #id { code }

```
<div id = "something" class="price-plans">
        <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id = "somethingElse" class="price-plans">
        <p><a href="/account/sign_up?plan=little_birdy" class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</a></p>
    </div>


#something{
code
}

#somethingElse{
code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .plan-price {
    float: right;
    margin: 83px 20px 20px;
}
 .private-eye {
      margin: 40px;
 }

 .little-birdy {
      margin: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.